# How to debug Sitefinity 4.0 crashes?

Tags: sitefinity-4

I'm new to Sitefinity and I want know how to approach debugging in general. I have a specific case here but my question is larger than this specific case.

So here is my case:

I've created a template (from the Sitefinity backend) and a few of pages based on that template. At some point I changed the template and saves/published the modifications. Now, when I open the template I get a yellow screen of death that says:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index]
   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.AddAt(Int32 index, Control child) +11236150
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ZoneEditor.ProcessMisplacedControls() +1435
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ZoneEditor.CreateChildControls() +82
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +182
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +60
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4185
```

I suppose the Sitefinity template designer generated invalid markup somewhere (see the ProcessMisplacedControls method).

How do I investigate this this and how can I repair my template? Can I see the template markup somewhere to try and fix it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the template and recreating it?